# Add a select field on Django form without saving on database

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that refers to a model into the database so, each time is filled and a user click SUBMIT, the form is saved on the database.

The form has a series of fields took directly from the Django Model. See below.

My problem is that, I want to add a new field, a select field, that have as option inside data I've processed from the backend via the home view and, when the form is submitted, it passes the data selected to the same view so I can elaborate from there. I don't want this field to be saved on the database with the `form.save()`

Is there a way to have this kind of "hybrid" form where part of the data/field are taken from the database and others are just added by me?

### models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    testTitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    testDescription = models.TextField()
    sequenzaTest = models.ForeignKey("SequenzaMovimento", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    numeroCicli = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    dataInizio = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    dataFine = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True)
    testFinito = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    testInPausa = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dataUltimaPausa = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    workerID = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.testTitle
    

class StartWorker(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('testTitle', 'testDescription', 'sequenzaTest', 'numeroCicli')

        widgets = {
            'testTitle': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'testDescription': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'sequenzaTest': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'numeroCicli': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

### views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StartWorker(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_info = form.save()
            print("ID oggetto creato", form_info.id)
            # print(form.cleaned_data['dataInizio'])
            print("Ultima data aggiunta", Test.objects.get(pk=form_info.id).dataInizio.isoformat("T","seconds"))
        return redirect("home")
    
    else:
        form = StartWorker()
        return render(
            request,
            'dashboard/index.html',
            {
                "form": form,
            }
        )
```

### index.html

```
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just add your other fields to the `ModelForm` and process them as required. You can use the form's `__init__` to fix up the choices for your field.

```
class StartWorker(ModelForm):
    somethingElse = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=())
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('testTitle', 'testDescription', 'sequenzaTest', 'numeroCicli')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        something_choices = kwargs.pop("something_choices")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields["somethingElse"].choices = something_choices
```

...

```
form = StartWorker(request.POST, something_choices=[('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B')])
...
if form.is_valid():
   something = form.cleaned_data.pop("somethingElse")
   # do something...
   test_instance = form.save()
```

(That `Test.objects.get(pk=form_info.id)` is unnecessary, by the way, you already get the `Test` instance from `form.save()`.)

Comment: The problem here is also: how do I pass the dictionary/array of my option dynamically to the form on the select field when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there's another way to do it.

In the view, if the method is not POST, I can process the data from the backend (in my case was the list of COM port) creating a dictionary and passing it to the context like:

```
    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    ports_array = []

    for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
        ports_array.append({
            "port":port,
            "desc":desc,
        })

    form = StartWorker()
    return render(
        request,
        'dashboard/index.html',
        {
            "form": form,
            "ports": ports_array,
        }
    )
```

then on the frontend I can print it with

```
   <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <label>Seleziona COM:</label>
        <select class="form-select" title="select-com" id="slctCOM" name="slctCOM">
          <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
          {% for port in ports %}
          <option value={{port.port}}>{{port.desc}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
    
        </select>
        <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And finally, when there's a POST request I can get the value via

```
 if request.method == "POST":
    slctCOM = request.POST.get('slctCOM')
```

With this approch there was no need to edit the actual Python Form Class

Comment: With this approach you end up writing more code, as you need to write the select yourself... but suit yourself, I suppose.